# Sidebar CSS transition not applying

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I'm trying to add a transition but it doesn't work.

I added a transition to my links and expect changes on hover state I used transition a lot, but sometimes this happens to me and I don't know why this property doesn't work

This is my code:

```html
<div id="sidebar">
    <ul class="nav-main-ul">
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home" style="padding-right: 13px"></i>Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav-title">Airports</li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="far fa-paper-plane" style="padding-right: 13px"></i>North Airports</a>
            <ul class="nav-dropdown">
                <li><a href="">LLBG | Tel-Aviv</a></li>
                <li><a href="">LLSD | Sde Dov</a></li>
                <li><a href="">LLHZ | Herzliya</a></li>
                <li><a href="">LLHA | Haifa</a></li>
                <li><a href="">LLIB | Rosh Pina</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#"><i class="far fa-paper-plane" style="padding-right: 13px"></i>South Airports</a>
            <ul class="nav-dropdown">
                <li><a href="">LLOV | Ovda</a></li>
                <li><a href="">LLET | Eilat</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-title">Airstrips</li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#"><i class="far fa-paper-plane" style="padding-right: 13px"></i>North Airstrips</a>
            <ul class="nav-dropdown">
                <li><a href="">LLKS | Kiryat Shmona</a></li>
                <li><a href="">LLBO | Habonim</a></li>
                <li><a href="">LLMG | Megido</a></li>
            </ul>                
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#"><i class="far fa-paper-plane" style="padding-right: 13px"></i>South Airstrips</a>
            <ul class="nav-dropdown">
                <li><a href="">LLBS | Beer Sheva</a></li>
                <li><a href="">LLMZ | Masada</a></li>
                <li><a href="">LLEY | Ein Yahav</a></li>
                <li><a href="">LLYO | Yotvata</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-title">Miscellaneous</li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-headphones-alt" style="padding-right: 13px"></i>ATC Tools</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```csss
#sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #151719;
    margin-top: 13px;
    list-style-type: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 500ms linear;
    -moz-transition: all 500ms linear;
    -o-transition: all 500ms linear;
    transition: all 500ms linear;
}

#sidebar.active {
    left: -200px;
    -webkit-transition: all 500ms linear;
    -moz-transition: all 500ms linear;
    -o-transition: all 500ms linear;
    transition: all 500ms linear;
}
```

JS:

```js
function toggleSidebar() {
  document.getElementById("sidebar").classList.toggle('active');
}
```

transition doesn't work, I used Firefox, and I try on google chrome too,
it makes it jump to -200px.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to make a transition effect for `left` value whereas the default value of `left` property [is](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/left) `auto` so it can not be done from `auto` to `-200px` or vice versa. Therefore you just need to set an initial value for `left`, for example `#sidebar {left: 0}`

```js
var sidebarElement = document.getElementById("sidebar");

function toggleSidebar() {
  sidebarElement.classList.toggle('active');
}
```

```css
#sidebar {
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #151719;
  margin-top: 30px;
  list-style-type: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 500ms linear;
  -moz-transition: all 500ms linear;
  -o-transition: all 500ms linear;
  transition: all 500ms linear;
}

#sidebar.active {
  left: -200px;
  -webkit-transition: all 500ms linear;
  -moz-transition: all 500ms linear;
  -o-transition: all 500ms linear;
  transition: all 500ms linear;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar">
    <ul class="nav-main-ul">
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home" style="padding-right: 13px"></i>Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav-title">Airports</li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="far fa-paper-plane" style="padding-right: 13px"></i>North Airports</a>
            <ul class="nav-dropdown">
                <li><a href="">LLBG | Tel-Aviv</a></li>
                <li><a href="">LLSD | Sde Dov</a></li>
                <li><a href="">LLHZ | Herzliya</a></li>
                <li><a href="">LLHA | Haifa</a></li>
                <li><a href="">LLIB | Rosh Pina</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#"><i class="far fa-paper-plane" style="padding-right: 13px"></i>South Airports</a>
            <ul class="nav-dropdown">
                <li><a href="">LLOV | Ovda</a></li>
                <li><a href="">LLET | Eilat</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-title">Airstrips</li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#"><i class="far fa-paper-plane" style="padding-right: 13px"></i>North Airstrips</a>
            <ul class="nav-dropdown">
                <li><a href="">LLKS | Kiryat Shmona</a></li>
                <li><a href="">LLBO | Habonim</a></li>
                <li><a href="">LLMG | Megido</a></li>
            </ul>                
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#"><i class="far fa-paper-plane" style="padding-right: 13px"></i>South Airstrips</a>
            <ul class="nav-dropdown">
                <li><a href="">LLBS | Beer Sheva</a></li>
                <li><a href="">LLMZ | Masada</a></li>
                <li><a href="">LLEY | Ein Yahav</a></li>
                <li><a href="">LLYO | Yotvata</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-title">Miscellaneous</li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-headphones-alt" style="padding-right: 13px"></i>ATC Tools</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<button onclick="toggleSidebar()">Toggle Sidebar</button>
```

Hope to help.